# How to position elements (nav, h1) header template [http://html5up.net/uploads/demos/alpha/][1] in the center?

Tags: html, css

How to position elements (nav, h1) header template http://html5up.net/uploads/demos/alpha/ in the center? `margin:0auto;` not work.

Comment: Please elaborate your problem, what do you mean not work?

Comment: Please include your CSS and HTML in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since the element header#header is absolute, center it with set to it the dimensions and the margin/left-position, like this:

```
position: absolute;
width: 540px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -270px;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
h1{

   width: 47%;
   text-align: right;
}

#nav{

   width: 50%;
  float: right;
}
```